# QTextEdit / whole UI of PyQt5 behaves differently on Android when virtual keyboard active

Tags: python, android, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a small PyQt5 / pyqtdeploy based app that runs on desktop systems as well as on Android. Inside the MainWindow there is a `QTextEdit` widget with its `textChanged` signal connected to some method.

Everything seems to work well on Android until I enter the `QTextEdit` instance and the virtual keyboard pops up. I can enter text but `on_textChanged()` will only be called when I leave the text field and thus the keyboard disappears.

It also looks like as the whole `update()` method of my MainWindow doesn't get called as well.

Is the Qt event system somehow disabled when the virtual keyboard is active?

(I'm using PyQt5.15.0 on Linux and Android 9)

Comment: It seems like a known and yet unresolved issue that, due to the nature of virtual keyboards on mobile devices, won't probably ever be solved (I suppose that there could be problems with prediction/autocorrection and how Qt behaves on input changes, but we do know that input fields do react on input). See qt bugs [40739](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40739), [67809](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-67809) and [79240](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-79240). While all relate to QLineEdit, due to their implementation, it seems reasonable that they affect *any* text input field.

Comment: Looks like setting `ImhSensitiveData` (`textEdit.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhSensitiveData)`) turns of 'intelligent' virtual keyboard features but events are handled as expected then.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately right now it seems like the only available workaround.